# Lodash - How to merge two arrays of objects based on key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to concat two arrays of objects with lodash. I have these two array and I use concat operator in this way:

```
 var array1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'doc1' }, { id: 2, name: 'doc2' }];
 var array2 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:3, name:'doc3'}, {id:4, name:'doc4'}];

 var array3 = _.concat(array1, array2);
```

I would like an array like this

```
 [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:2, name:'doc2'}, {id:3, name:'doc3'}, {id:4, name:'doc4'}]]
```

But with concat function I obtain an array like this:

```
  [{ id: 1, name: 'doc1' }, { id: 1, name: 'doc1' }, { id: 2, name: 'doc2' }, { id: 3, name: 'doc3' }, { id: 4, name: 'doc4' }]]
```

I want to avoid the repetition of an object with the same id...Which kind of operator can I use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the result using `merge` and `keyBy` lodash functions.

```js
var array1 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:2, name:'doc2'}];
var array2 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:3, name:'doc3'}, {id:4, name:'doc4'}];

var merged = _.merge(_.keyBy(array1, 'id'), _.keyBy(array2, 'id'));
var values = _.values(merged);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`_.unionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unionBy) to combine two arrays, and remove duplicates that have the same unique field (`id` in this case). The lodash's union methods create an array of unique values. The `_.unionBy()` method accepts an iteratee which is invoked for each element of each array to generate the criterion by which uniqueness is computed.

```js
const array1 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:2, name:'doc2'}];
const array2 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:3, name:'doc3'}, {id:4, name:'doc4'}];

const result = _.unionBy(array1, array2, 'id');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have uniqWith in lodash that allows you to do this:
https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith

```js
var array1 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:2, name:'doc2'}];
var array2 = [{id:1, name:'doc1'}, {id:3, name:'doc3'}, {id:4, name:'doc4'}];

var values = _.uniqWith([...array1, ...array2], _.isEqual);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```